# AngularJS - Calling service in config

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to call `AuthenticationService.logout()` on a `401 http error`. However, I can't make it work. I suppose I can't inject a service to the config, but how can I achieve this then?

```
myApp.config(['$httpProvider', 'AuthenticationService', function ($httpProvider, AuthenticationService) {
    var interceptor = ['$rootScope','$q', function(scope, $q) {

        function success(response) {
            return response;
        }

        function error(response) {
            var status = response.status;

            if (status == 401) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                var req = {
                    config: response.config,
                    deferred: deferred
                }

                /* LOGOUT HERE */
                AuthenticationService.logout();

                return deferred.promise;
            }

            return $q.reject(response);

        }

        return function(promise) {
            return promise.then(success, error);
        }

    }];
    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push(interceptor);

}]);
```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: don't think `scope` is valid in config.... use `$rootScope.$broadcast`, what erros are thrown?

Comment: Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: AuthenticationService from myApp

Comment: you haven't included service as dependency

Comment: injecting in wrong place